# Changing the shape of a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have `n` arrays of shape

```
(86,)
```

I have an empty array

```
complete = np.array([])
```

To which I want to append these `n` arrays. When I do it right now using this

```
complete = np.append(complete, feature_1)
```

when I keep appending the array shape changes to `(172,)` , `(258)`... etc , but I would like to append in such a way that it goes like this `(1, 86)`, `(2, 86)` , `(3, 86)` etc.. resulting in the final shape I would like  `(n, 86)`.

Any suggestions on how I may be able to achieve this would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Efficiency is not really on my priority list at the moment, getting this done is

Comment: @ roganjosh Will look into it

Comment: I think you want [vstack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html)

Comment: Post a small example of your shape array.

Comment: @kabanus the shape of my array is `(86,)` , and i have 128 of those, So i would like to loop through these array's and get  shape of  `(128, 86)`, hope im clear here

Comment: I deleted my initial comment but I think the principle is worth keeping. Don't approach numpy arrays as lists, appending requires a whole new array and memory to be allocated. This is implied in you instantiating an empty array. It really is very inefficient. It may be better to create an array with the correct dimensions beforehand e.g. using `np.empty()` and then assigning the rows.

Comment: Dont think i was clear in stating the question, Have made edits to change that

Comment: @ raganjosh will keep this in mind

Comment: What structure are these arrays stored in currently? Presumably the `n` arrays are in some container. Or are they individually named? I'm curious as to whether we have something to iterate through to access each individual array.

Comment: The `n `arrays are not stored anywhere but  every iteration will create an `ith` array of `n `

Comment: did you see what np.append says about the axis parameter?

Comment: don't use np.concatenate or np.append in a loop.  list append is better.

Comment: I didnt check about the np.append axis parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you'd better create an empty 2D array and fill it later...

```
import numpy as np

N = how_many()
L = how_long()

complete = np.empty((N, L), dtype=float)

for i in range(N):
    complete(i, :) = extract_feature(i)
```

In place of `dtype=float` you can use a different numeric type, as required by your problem.

E.g.,

```
In [14]: a = np.empty((2,4), dtype=float)

In [15]: for i in (0, 1):
    ...:     a[i,:] = np.ones(4)*i
    ...:     

In [16]: a
Out[16]: 
array([[0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1.]])
```

#### Addendum

**Comment on efficiency**   If one knows beforehand the dimensions of an array they are going to construct row-by-row, the approach sketched above is better, because it avoids constantly
alllocating new memory, copying the temporary result and the new row to the new memory and deallocating the memory used to hold the previous temporary result.

**Alternative using concatenation**   If, on the other hand, one doesn't know beforehand how many rows will be produced during the creation of the array, or if one insists on using a sub-optimal solution, **they can use** `np.vstack`, **encapsulating the productions of new rows in a *generator***

```
import numpy as np

def features_factory(stuff):
    while true:
        feature = new_feature(stuff)
        if feature:
            yield feature
        else:
            return

complete = np.vstack(features_factory(todays_stuff))
```

E.g.,

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: np.random.seed((2018+7+8)) # today's stuff... ;)

In [3]: def features_factory(stuff):
   ...:     n = 0
   ...:     while True:
   ...:         if n<stuff:
   ...:             yield np.ones(5)*n
   ...:             n = n+1
   ...:         else:
   ...:             return        

In [4]: complete = np.vstack(features_factory(np.random.randint(5,11)))

In [5]: complete
Out[5]: 
array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [2., 2., 2., 2., 2.],
       [3., 3., 3., 3., 3.],
       [4., 4., 4., 4., 4.],
       [5., 5., 5., 5., 5.],
       [6., 6., 6., 6., 6.],
       [7., 7., 7., 7., 7.]])

In [6]:
```

Comment: let me check this out

Comment: this solution Works

Comment: Not only it Works, it's also efficient because one doesn't go through, iteration after iteration, to 1. allocating new memory 2. copying what has be done so far and 3. marking for garbage collection the memory that was previously used...

Comment: Hi , you think what i want to achieve can be done using a concatenation operation too ?, i mean as i loop keep concatenating the array's?